# How to test atexit using pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I was trying to make a script of mine save some data before it exits. I looked at the atexit documentation and I was wondering if there is a way to test the code gets executed when the process is terminated (more specifically, using pytest). Maybe there is no point in doing it, but is it possible? Here is my code

**method that atexit calls**

```py
@classmethod
def save_state(cls, program_state, program_manager):
    running = program_state.get_curr_running()
    print("Saving the current state upon exit...")
    pruned = program_manager.prune_programs(running)
    for pg in pruned:
        pg.end_now()
    DataManager.update_pg_times(pruned)
```

```py
# Before the program is shutdown, currently running programs are updated
import atexit
atexit.register(DataManager.save_state, program_state, program_manager)
```

Comment: _Maybe there is no point in doing it_ - I would agree on that, there are tests for the `atexit` module in the stdlib already. Write a test that calls `save_state` with appropriate arguments instead and you're good. You can also write a system test that calls your program in a subprocess and verifies the program does what it should on exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `pytest`, you could use its `monkeypatching` fixture to test this.

In my usecase, I've `atexit.register`-ed a teardown function which logs some debugging information at the end of the program. In my unittest, I wanted to verify that if an exception is raised inside the flow of my program that my teardown function would run  and would do the logging it was required to do.

Here's a part of the code under test (assume module named c.py under a/b/c.py):

```
import atexit

def teardown():
    # do whatever actions are needed at the end
    # do some logging
    log.info(...)

    ...

# register this function to run at the end
atexit.register(teardown)
```

and in pytest I have a snippet like the following, which checks that an exception was raised and then explicitly fakes the end of the program by monkeypatching `atexit.register`:

```py
import pytest
from a.b import c


def test_my_test_case_name(monkeypatching)
    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        teardown_fn: Callable[[], None] = lambda: None  # noqa

        def set_teardown_fn(fn):
            nonlocal teardown_fn
            teardown_fn = fn

        m.setattr(c.atexit, "register", set_teardown_fn)
        io_stream = io.StringIO()
        with redirect_stdout(io_stream), redirect_stderr(io_stream):
            with pytest.raises(
                RuntimeError,
            ):
                function_under_test()

            # explicitly call the atexit registered function - i.e., fake the end-of-program.
            teardown_fn()

    # now assert that e.g., the logs you expected to get printed from your teardown function do get printed.
    assert "some-expected-str" in io_stream.getvalue()
```